# Boundary condition not working on infinite place (uniformly charged) with dielectric on one side and vacuum on the other

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, gauss-law, boundary-conditions, dielectric

To describe this situation mathematically, we have an infinite place at $z = 0$. For $z > 0$ a vacuum is present while for $z < 0$ a linear dielectric with dielectric constant $\epsilon_{r}$ is present. Then we use Gauss' to find the displacement field $D$
$$ 
\iint_{S} \vec{D}\cdot\vec{dA} = Q_{\text{fenc}} \tag{1}
$$
where $S$ is a closed surface and $ Q_{\text{fenc}}$ is the free charge that is enclosed. Now if we place a box that encapsulates a portion of the infinite place we can write Gauss' law as

$$
\iint_{S} \vec{D}\cdot\vec{dA} = \iint_{\text{Top}} \vec{D}\cdot\vec{dA} + \iint_{\text{Bottom}} \vec{D}\cdot\vec{dA} = A\sigma_f. \tag{2}
$$

The displacement field is in the same direction as the unit normal $\vec{dA}$ therefore we get
$$
D_{\text{Top}} + D_{\text{Bottom}} = \sigma_f. \tag{3}
$$

Since we have a linear dielectric we get
$$
D_{\text{Top}} + D_{\text{Bottom}} = \epsilon_0E+\epsilon_0\epsilon_rE = \epsilon_0E(1+\epsilon_r) = \sigma_f. \tag{5}
$$

With this we get

$$
\vec{E} = \frac{\sigma_f}{\epsilon_0(1+1)}\hat{z}\quad \text{for }  z>0\tag{6}
$$
$$
\vec{E} = -\frac{\sigma_f}{\epsilon_0(1+\epsilon_r)}\hat{z}\quad \text{for } z<0. \tag{7}
$$
The electric field in the vacuum is correct because it matches with the case of vacuums on both sides of an infinite plane. However, two problems that I find, in Griffiths Introduction to Electrodynamics he states that 
$$
\vec{D}^{\perp}_{\text{above}} - \vec{D}^{\perp}_{\text{below}} = \sigma \tag{8}
$$
where $\sigma$ is the free charge (if I am not mistaken). If we try this with the displacement fields found for the infinite planes using $\vec{D} = \epsilon_0\epsilon_r\vec{E}$. We get

$$
\sigma_f(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\epsilon_r}{1+\epsilon_r}) =^{?} \sigma_f. \tag{9} 
$$
It does not seem possible to equate the LHS and RHS. This should mean that I have made a mistake somewhere because I have tested the boundary conditions for other situations and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Gauss's law is an integral over a closed surface. If $\vec{D}$ is in the same direction at the top and bottom of your closed box, then $\vec{D}\cdot d\vec{A}$ changes sign. i.e. You should get
$$D_{\rm top} - D_{\rm bottom} = \sigma_f$$

Then I don't understand what you are doing in the next line. The E-field isn't continuous across the boundary.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It turns out that I did an error in equations (6) and (7). However, $D_{\text{top}} - D_{\text{bottom}} should hold even if the E-field is discontinuous or am I mistaken?

Comment: @greatangle The equation in my answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I had made an error in equation (6) and (7) and this leads to the problem in equation (9). The E-fields are 
$$
\vec{E}_{\text{Top}} = \frac{\sigma_f}{\epsilon_0(1+\epsilon_r)}\hat{z} \quad z > 0 \tag{10},
$$

$$
\vec{E}_{\text{Below}} = -\frac{\sigma_f}{\epsilon_0(1+\epsilon_r)}\hat{z} \quad z <0 \tag{11}.
$$

Then equation (9) becomes

$$
D_{\text{above}}^{\perp} - D_{\text{below}}^{\perp} = \epsilon_0\cdot 1E_{\text{Top}}-\epsilon_0 \epsilon_rE_{\text{Below}} = \sigma_f(\frac{1+\epsilon_r}{1+\epsilon_r}) = \sigma_f.
$$
Therefore the boundary condition holds in this case.